# Locking a file/ folder on android. How to go about it?

Tags: java, android, file-handling, android-file

I want to lock a folder on android to prevent the user from accessing that particular data from anywhere outside the application. 
1. The data in the folders is too large to keep it in assets or Raw folders or even inside apk.
2. Decrypting the data takes a lot of time.

How do these file managers lock particular folders?

[Very Android File Protector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.veryandroid.fileprotector&hl=en) : This app in particular locks the folders. Once the folder is locked it has  .LOCK as suffix. How does this work out?

I went through the **FileLock** in **java/nio/channels/FileLock** but could not really figure out how it works.

Could any please give me some clue on how this can be done?

Comment: dot before folder will hide the folder.

Comment: @AndrewThompson : I am developing an app for a client where in he wants to prevent his data from being leaked thus locking the folder.

Comment: @android_dev : giving a dot before the folder also doesnt help. folders having . as a prefix can be accessed through multiple file explorers.

Comment: Then remove the excution permission for that file and try if your removing that excution permission then no one can access

Comment: @android_dev : can you please elaborate?

Comment: Change the file permissions. file.setExcutable(false,false)

Comment: I want the files to be inaccessible through file explorer, PC etc.. This doesn't help me attain that.